# What happens if two udev rules assign the same name to different network interfaces?

Tags: udev, network-interface

What happens if two udev rules try to assign the same name to two different network interfaces (i.e. udev name collision)?

The first assignment to occur will succeed?

And the second assignment to occur will (silently?) fail, meaning the second interface will still have its "original" name?

Or does something else happen?

Comment: The obvious way to find out is to try ... Did you try?

Comment: Is there some easy way to observe what happens inside udev?  Some udev debugging and logging capabilities?  This RedHat bug makes it sound like there is no logging.  https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=997573  There is more somewhat related info here: https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/

Comment: That's a completely different question, so I suggest you ask a new one. You can observe the outcome of name assignments easily by looking at the MAC address.